# Email body format and modification

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, email, powershell-1.0

I am using below code in Powershell to get Email in proper table format from a plain text file **output.txt**:

**code.ps1**

```
$smtpServer = "sunny@domain.com"
$smtpFrom = "process@abc.com"
$smtpTo = "sunny@abc.com"
$messageSubject = "Data"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true

$body = Get-Content C:\output.txt | Out-String
$body = $body -replace '^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><th style = "border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$1</th><th style = "border: 1px solid black;   background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$2</th><th style = "border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px;">$3</th></tr>'
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$1</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$2</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$3</td></tr>'
$body = '<body><table style = "border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">' + $body + '</table></body>'
$message.Body = $body

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

I want to do following changes in receiving Email structure:

**Change1:**

Email is coming in below format in table:

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM           PROJECTSERVER1   PROJECTSERVER2
Windows                   1.36             4.42
Linux12                   2.78             5.76
MacOS                     3.45             6.39
Ubuntu                    4.12             0.00
Android                   0.00             3.46
FreePhysicalMemory        30.12            31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize    48.00            48.00
CPULoadPercentage         2                4
```

but, how can i align the values for 2nd and 3rd columns only in center like below?

```
OPERATINGSYSTEM           PROJECTSERVER1   PROJECTSERVER2
Windows                       1.36             4.42
Linux12                       2.78             5.76
MacOS                         3.45             6.39
Ubuntu                        4.12             0.00
Android                       0.00             3.46
FreePhysicalMemory           30.12            31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize       48.00            48.00
CPULoadPercentage              2                4
```

**Change2:**

How i can add below notes at end, outside of table in email body:

```
All memory values are in GB.

Note: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it.
```

**Change3:**

How i can send this Email to multiple recipients with multiple CC's. Can i add email ids separated by commas like **$smtpTo = "administrator@abc.com,dbadmin@abc.com..."** ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change1**: Change your table row definition from

```
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$1</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$2</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$3</td></tr>'
```

to

```
$body = $body -replace '\n(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', '<tr><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">$1</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;text-align:center;">$2</td><td style = "border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;text-align:center;">$3</td></tr>'
```

Explanation: Added `text-align:center` to the style definition of the table cells.

**Change2**: Just add the text at the end of the mail:

```
$body = '<body><table style = "border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">' + $body + '</table><br/>All memory values are in GB.<br/><br/>Note: This is an automatically generated email, please don't reply to it.<br/></body>'
```

**Change3**: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h1s04he7(v=vs.100).aspx you are correct: add multiple email adresses separated by `,`

Comment: Yes..found the error and corrected..working perfect now..Thanks a lot Ocaso!!..all the three changes made successfully..!:)